# Qt - QImage translate using

Tags: image, qt, qt4

I’m just beggining to use Qt’s QTransform.
I’m trying to translate a simple image but I can’t do it! In the form, I have a label named “rulo” and a button wich triggers the following code when clicked.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QImage canvas = QImage("/home/andresdido/Descargas/ruleta.png","PNM");

    // QImage canvas;
    QTransform translating;
    QImage trasladada;

    qreal ancho = (qreal) canvas.width()/2;
    qreal alto = (qreal) canvas.height()/2;

    translating.translate(ancho,alto);

    trasladada=canvas.transformed(translating);
    ui->rulo->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(trasladada));

    return;

}
```

Both QImage’s, canvas and trasladada are just the same! Just as if the translation had no effect at all. (Obviously, both Qimage’s also look the same, since their “data” is perfectly equal).

I've seen there is an unanswered topic here which is, in a way, similar:
[Qt image move/rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584285/qt-image-move-rotation)
Any ideas about why the translation has no effect? Thanks!

Comment: in cases like this i add some output for debugging. `#include <QDebug>` and check for `height()` and `width()` of the `canvas` and the `trasladada` as well as if they are identical, what the content of the image looks like.

Comment: What is "PNM"? I meant "PNG" instead?

Comment: Possibly why it didn't have an effect: Internally, the transformation matrix is adjusted to compensate for unwanted translation, i.e. transformed() returns the smallest image containing all transformed points of the original image. [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#image-transformations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same using the following sample code:

```
QImage canvas = QImage("source.png");
QImage trasladada(canvas.width(), canvas.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
trasladada.fill(Qt::white);

QPainter painter(&trasladada);
qreal ancho = canvas.width() / 2.0;
qreal alto = canvas.height() / 2.0;    
painter.drawImage(QPointF(ancho, alto), canvas);   

ui->rulo->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(trasladada));
```